# What is the equivalent of "always()" in guzzle promises?

Tags: promise, guzzle, guzzle6

I have some code which uses guzzle 5 and I am trying to upgrade it to guzzle 6. One of the changes in guzzle 6 is that it no longer makes use of the [`react/promise`](https://packagist.org/packages/react/promise) library and instead uses [its own promise library](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/promises). My understanding is that the two are not interchangeable.

There is code which uses the the `always()` function from `react/promise` like so:

```php
$promise->then(
    // function
)->otherwise(
    // function
)->always(
    // function
);
```

The problem I have is that guzzle promises don't have an `always()` function. According to the `react/promise` [documentation](https://github.com/reactphp/promise#promiseinterfacealways), this function acts as cleanup for a promise chain in a similar way to the `finally` block in a `try`/`catch`/`finally` sequence.

How can I emulate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code from the always in both then and otherwise

Comment: What my distillation of the problem has masked is the fact that there's actually four `otherwise()` blocks, so this approach would mean duplicating the contents of the `always()` block multiple times. Even if it gets refactored into another function, there is the opportunity for human error. This approach looks like it would certainly work, but I'll see if any alternatives are offered.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Promise class which extends from `\GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise`

```
class ReactCompatiblePromise extends \GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise {

    public function always(callable $always)
    {
        return $this->then($always, $always);
    }        
}
```

But unfortunately you cannot set the Promise class which is used within the guzzle project.

All promises created will always be an instance of `\GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise`

If you don't mind doing something hacky then you could take a copy of the file, make your amendments and autoload your file instead.

Keep the original class name (`Promise`) and namespace `\GuzzleHttp\Promise` and dont extend or use the original `\GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise` class.

Assuming you're using composer you could update your composer.json file to include

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["ReactCompatiblePromise.php"]
    }
}
```